Custom LaTeX Command for Consecutive Superscripts with Correct Alignment After Large Symbols
I am writing my master's thesis on Formal Concept Analysis and I want to create a custom command for the derivation operators. They are superscript arrows with some optional argument, and would look like this:
\[ x^{\uparrow_i}, \quad a^{\downarrow^i} \]

So, my first try was to define these commands as:
\newcommand{\up}[1][]{^{\uparrow_{#1}}}
\newcommand{\down}[1][]{^{\downarrow^{#1}}}

However, there are instances where these operators will be applied one after the other, and
\[ x\up\down \]

creates a "double superscript" error. This has a simple fix, just add brackets around the expression like so:
\newcommand{\up}[1][]{{^{\uparrow_{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\down}[1][]{{^{\downarrow^{#1}}}}

This has been my command for the whole time I've been writing the thesis, but recently I found an instance where this doesn't work as I want it to.
\[ \Big( \bigvee p_i \Big)\up \]

This code doesn't place the arrow as high as it should be, like in this code
\[ \Big( \bigvee p_i \Big)^{\uparrow} \]

Basically I want to define a command that satisfies these two requisites: I have to be able to write them one after another and they should place at the correct height when next to big symbols.
Here is a MWE with what I have:
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\up}[1][]{{^{\uparrow_{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\down}[1][]{{^{\downarrow^{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

Expected output:
\[
  x^{\uparrow_i}, \quad x^{\uparrow_i\downarrow_j}, \quad \Big( \bigcup S \Big)^{\uparrow_i}
\]

How I want to write it:
\[
  x\up[i], \quad x\up[i]\down[j], \quad \Big( \bigcup S \Big)\up[i]
\]

\end{document}


My try: I have been looking all over the internet and this forum in order to find a solution, and I have come up with something (though I haven't been able to make it work). Using the \@ifnextchar command I can tell whether there is a \down command after \up (or \up after \down) and proceed accordingly. What I have is the following:

I create a toggle for when I am writing the operators, say writing (for example using the package etoolbox), and set it to false.
I create an environment superscriptenv to write its contents in superscript.
When I start \up or \down, if writing was set to false, I start the superscript environment, write the corresponding arrow and toggle writing to true.
If the next command is down or up, then don't do anything else. Otherwise, end the superscript environment and toggle writing false.

Below is the code I have written, only with the up operator.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox, environ}

\newtoggle{writing}
\togglefalse{writing}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{superscriptenv}{^{\BODY}}

\newcommand{\up}[1][]{
  \iftoggle{writing}{}{%
    \toggletrue{writing}%
    \begin{superscriptenv}%
  }%
  \uparrow_{#1}
  \@ifnextchar\up{}{%
    \end{superscriptenv}%
    \togglefalse{writingup}%
  }
}

\begin{document}

\[
  x\up[i], \quad x\up[I]\up[j], \quad \Big( \bigcup S \Big)\up[i]
\]

\end{document}

However, this doesn't compile because "\begin{superscriptenv} ended by \end{document}". Would appreciate it if anyone got any ideas. Thanks in advance!

You have almost the right idea.
Instead of using a toggle and an Environ, it is easier to use the following logic:

Everytime \up or \down starts, push the symbol that it would add to a queue.
Check if the next token is an \up or a \down. If so, do nothing.
If the next token is neither \up nor \down, bring the whole queue, and reset the queue.

\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@sjmr@temp{}
\newcommand\up[1][]{%
        \expandafter\def\expandafter\@sjmr@temp\expandafter{\@sjmr@temp\uparrow_{#1}}
\@ifnextchar\up{}{\@ifnextchar\down{}{^{\@sjmr@temp}\def\@sjmr@temp{}}}}
\newcommand\down[1][]{%
        \expandafter\def\expandafter\@sjmr@temp\expandafter{\@sjmr@temp\downarrow_{#1}}
\@ifnextchar\up{}{\@ifnextchar\down{}{^{\@sjmr@temp}\def\@sjmr@temp{}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
        x\up[i], \quad x\up[i]\down[j], \quad \Big( \bigcup S \Big)\up[i]\up[j]\down[k]
\]
\end{document}


Thank you for the answer, this works great!

You can try following macros:
\def\isnextchar#1#2#3{\def\tmp{#1{#2}{#3}}\futurelet\next\isnextcharA}
\def\isnextcharA{\expandafter\isnextcharB\tmp}
\def\isnextcharB#1#2#3{\ifx\next#1\afterfi{#2}\else\afterfi{#3}\fi}
\def\afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}
\def\up{^\bgroup\upA.}
\def\upA#1{\isnextchar[{\updown\uparrow_}{\updown\uparrow_[]}}
\def\updown#1#2[#3]{#1#2{#3}\isnextchar\down{\downA}{\isnextchar\up{\upA}{\egroup}}}
\def\down{^\brgroup\downA.}
\def\downA#1{\isnextchar[{\updown\downarrow^}{\updown\downarrow^[]}}

Test:
$$ x\up[i]\down[j], \Bigr)\up[i]\down[j]\down[k] $$

The main idea is that the superscript is opened by ^\bgroup and then the text is scanned and printed until the superscript is finished by something else than \up or \down. Then it is closed by \egroup

Thank you for your answer. I accepted the one given by @Willie because I find it easier to understand.
